# Bar between two x-axis values with chart.js

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart

I'm working with bar charts like this one :

[image]

And I'm looking for a way to display the bars between two x-axis values.
I would like the bars to be visually linked to a range of x-axis values, not only one.

In my example, the first bar needs to be between 30 & 35.